# How do I mimic the windows 7 UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dwm, aero-glass

I want to try and get the same look as Windows 7, with the aero glass dropping down just a little bit so that there can be a back button/address bar/ search box. Are there any tutorials on how to do this? I really need something simple, as I tried looking at a few other [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx) that try to explain how to use DWM with c# and I get totally lost.

Comment: Isn't this something more suited to WPF than WinForms?

Comment: not sure, I am trying to make a winforms, maybe that is where I am going wrong?

Comment: Absolutely use WPF, WinForms is a nightmare for this sort of thing. Combine it with http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack and you're on to a winner.

Comment: @Tom: Why didn't you put that as an answer?  That is exactly what it seems he is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done as an answer :)

*Absolutely* use WPF, WinForms is a nightmare for this sort of thing. Combine it with http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack and you're on to a winner.

Answer (score 1):

Ive been using the glass_full class from the site below on WinForms and and it works great.
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/146813-glass-form-dwmapidll-api/

I found a workaround for the black text issue with WinForms is to simply set backcolor and transparencyKey to a unused color. 
(To prevent clickthrough, make sure the red and blue values are different, I use 221,222,223 as my color values so it gracefully fallsback to grey without Aero)